# Can you use EF 4 and MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

It's been about 6 months since I did any coding. The life of a Tech. Lead. Quick question-Can I use EF 4 and MVC 2? Or do I HAVE TO upgrade to MVC 3?

Comment: Incidentally, you say MVC2 in the title, but you tagged this MVC3. Makes no difference for the answer, though.

Comment: Hey uncle "GOOGLE" has all the answers, this is not a question you can't find an answer on your own.

Comment: @IamStalker That's what the down vote button is for...

Comment: @Andrew Barber I know didn't wanted to do it, i don't like to downvote ppl.

Comment: @IAmStalker Down voting would have been less rude, IMO. YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MVC does not care what you use for the model. You can use EF, ADO.NET, XML files, a web service, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that now. Just one of those moments.